# Express $det(A \otimes A)$ using trace and det of $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

Express $det(A \otimes A)$ using trace and det of $A$. I know that determinant is product of eigenvalues, and trace is sum. But i cannot procceed further. Any hints?

Comment: What is $A$? What does $\otimes$ mean here?

Comment: @EricWofsey $\otimes$ means tensor product. A is a linear operator

Comment: What do you mean by "tensor product"?  How are you tensoring a scalar and a linear operator?

Comment: Is it possible you meant $det(A\otimes A)$?

Comment: @CaptainLama yes, i will edit

Comment: Can you find a formula in the case where $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: It is very bad form to just start using a variable without saying what it is.  To be completely clear, is the following correct?  You have a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, a linear map $A:V\to V$, and you are asking to find a formula for the determinant of the map $A\otimes A:V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$?  (Don't comment, add these details to your question!)